# Запись данных в json php

Tags: php, вконтакте, api

```
                    elseif ($body[0] == '/баланс'){
                    $json = file_get_contents('users.json');
                    $UserData = json_decode($json, true);
                    $new_user = [
                        'id' => $this->from_id,
                        'balance' => 1500
                        ];
                    if($UserData['id'] != $this->from_id) {
                        file_put_contents('users.json', json_encode($new_user).PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
                    }
                    $self = ($this->random(['', '❤'])."Баланс: ".$new_user['balance']."$");
                }
```

Проблема в том, что если пользователь отправит сообщение "/баланс" 2 раза, то его 2 раза и запишет в файл, мне нужно чтобы если пользователь отправит сообщение /баланс 1 раз, и если его нет в файле то его записало в файл, а все следующие разы когда он снова напишет /баланс то данные уже брались из файла и выводились ему.
Конкретно какие данные: Баланс.
Надеюсь я объяснил всё понятно.

Comment: На глазок: у вас скрипт не рабочий, получается после 5 раз использования у вас 5 строк в файле с json-представлением, ОДНАКО `$UserData = json_decode($json, true);` - тут вы берете весь файл, и пытаетесь его декодировать, он вам выдаст `NULL` ибо у вас там 5 разных json-ов, а ему нужен только один.

Comment: Можете дать рабочий?

Comment: Т.е. вы как разработчик (программист) хотите взять у стороннего человека код ВАШЕЙ программы?

Comment: Конечно, где-то на полочке завалялось. Щас поищу...

Comment: ну хотя-бы объясните как это исправить?

Comment: Ну вам же указали на ошибку. Ну исправьте её.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел... -.-

Файл `users.json` - должен существовать - пустой.

```
elseif ($body[0] == '/баланс') {
    $FROM_ID = $this->from_id;
    $json = file_get_contents('users.json');
    $UserData = json_decode($json, true);
    if (!isset($UserData[$FROM_ID]))
    {
        $UserData[$FROM_ID] = 1500;
        // $UserData[$FROM_ID]['balance'] = 1500;
        file_put_contents('users.json', json_encode($UserData));
    }
    $self = ($this->random(['', '❤'])."Баланс: ".$UserData[$FROM_ID]."$");
    // $self = ($this->random(['', '❤'])."Баланс: ".$UserData[$FROM_ID]['balance']."$");
}
```

Comment: Благодарю! Извините за то что я сам не смог решить данную проблему, просто начал изучать php неделю назад.

Comment: @АминАлиев обращайтесь ;)

Comment: Ох и намаетесь вы с синхронизацией этого на реальном проекте. Хоть блокировку эксклюзивную добавьте.

Comment: @vp_arth а в идеале, добавить ООП, перевести эту дичь в БД. И вообще все переписать. Человек только учится, думаю ничего не поймает))